# Is it possible to pass a function to dynamic modal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal with dynamic title, and message, I would also like to provide it a dynamic function, when I test it; the function gets fired before the modal is shown, is there a way to not fire that function and instead put it into the scope var so it can be used in the reusable modal?

**Dynamic Modal:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmationModal-reusable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="confirmationTitle2">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="confirmationTitle2">{{reusableTitle}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{reusableMessage}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer bootstrap-iso">
        <button type="button" ng-click="{{reusableFunction}}" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$scope.Refresh = function(){
    //prompt for refresh, all unsaved items will be lost.
    $scope.reusableTitle = "Are you sure?";
    $scope.reusableMessage = "Are you sure you want to abandon changes and refresh from server?";
    $scope.reusableFunction = $scope.init();//how can I pass this function to the ng-click on my reusable modal?
    $("#confirmationModal-reusable").modal('show');
};

$scope.init = function() {
    //gets json from server...
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could something like this:

```
<button ng-click="reusableFunction('init')">Click this button</button>
```

And then in the controller do something like this:

```
$scope.reusableFunction = function (functionName){
    if(angular.isFunction($scope[functionName])){
       $scope[functionName]();
    }
}

$scope.init = function(){
    //do your stuff
}
```

And here is some more info on the `isFunction` call https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isFunction

Comment: This is more like what I wanted, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only thing you have to do is this

```
<button type="button" ng-click="reusableFunction()" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
```

Comment: If I do that then the function isn't reusable, I want to pass `init()` in this case and maybe next time pass `process()` or `danceAround()` - but maybe I could do `reusableFunction({{actualFunctionIwantToCall}})` and then have a `switch` in there to call the right function... if there is no other way to achieve what I am wanting.

Comment: You can redefine `$scope.reusableFunction` and assign new function

Comment: I tried the `ng-click=reusableFunction(reusableParam)` with `$scope.reusableFunction = function(func){
  switch(func){
   case "init()":
   $scope.init();
   break;
  }
 };` and it works, but it feels dirty, and it means that every time i want to call a new function i have to add it to my `switch` I don't love that, holding out and hoping for a better answer.